# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '...' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, database

This is the error I get when trying to run this query:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '307 307 307' to
>   data type int.

Query:

```
select count(sd.mrid)
    ,replace(replace(substring(sd.mrref_to_mr, charindex('l', sd.mrref_to_mr), len(sd.mrref_to_mr)), 'l', ''), 'x10', '')
where sd.mrref_to_mr like '%x10'
group by replace(replace(substring(sd.mrref_to_mr, charindex('l', sd.mrref_to_mr)), 'l', ''), 'x10', '')
    , imw.mrtitle
order by replace(replace(substring(sd.mrref_to_mr, charindex('l', sd.mrref_to_mr)), 'l', ''), 'x10', '') desc
```

The field that it's complaining about is something like:

`L5587x6 5587` or it will have something like `5587` or `L5587x6`

I need just the `5587` but I need it as a numeric value it seems.  I just need to match it to another field which is mrID and it is an int

Comment: With your most recent edit to your query, you no longer have a from clause.  (I'm not trying to be nit-picky, here, but if you're going to attempt a fairly complicated set of nested string functions in your query, you really do have to pay attention to the details.  The two version of your query that I have seen have both had basic syntax errors in them.  No one will be able to help you without seeing the actual query that is failing, instead of a syntactically incorrect similar query.)

Answer (score 0):

You have unmatching parenthesis in your SELECT clause.  Formatted it looks like:

```
select  count(sd.mrid) ,
        replace(
            replace(
                substring(sd.mrref)to_mr, charindex('l', sd.mrref_to_mr), len(sd.mrref_to_mr)
            ), 'l', ''
        ), 'x10', '')
```

I think you may have cut a function out and only removed a portion of it.

Comment: substring(sd.mrref)to)mr should've been substring(sd.mrref_to_mr

Comment: I'll update my answer when I can.  Right now the posted query has a different syntax error in it.